# Count no of rows with group by clause in criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, properties, hibernate-criteria

is there a way to write hibernate criteria for the following sql:

`select count(*) from tableA group by columnA, columnB, columnC;`

Basically, I want to exclude the group property from the select clause which is added by default.

Example:

```
session.createCriteria(TableA.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("columnA"))
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("columnB"))
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("columnC"))
    .add(Projections.rowCount()));
```

will result in

`select columnA, columnB, columnC, count(*) from tableA group by columnA, columnB, columnC;`

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found if this is possible? I'm in the exact same situation.

Comment: I posted a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030998/2114737

Answer (score 1):

refer below code::

```
Integer totalResult = ((Number)criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

You can also try this:::

```
int count = ((Long)getSession().createQuery("select count(*) from table_a group by column_a").uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

Comment: It can be done by HQL. I am just wondering whether it can be done by criteria. Thanks.